# Manage intrervals for PeriodicTask

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

My development is based on Windows Phone 8 and 8.1. This is a homebrew app so I'm not restricted by the market place.

I need a Periodic Task with an interval shorter than 30 min. Ideally, I would like an interval of 15 min. Unfortunately, there is a constraint that don't allow a periodic task to be running in an interval shorter than 30 min.

I know that I could use **ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest** in order to trick the system but i was thinking if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A background agent is triggered by the system's timer tick; the system timer tick is OS driven and cannot be changed *(well, I guess you can try to hack the OS)*

[Windows Phone, Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx)'s timer tick is set to 30 minutes

> Windows has a built-in timer that runs background tasks in 15-minute intervals. *Note that on Windows Phone, the interval is 30 minutes.*

[Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.freshnesstime.aspx) the restriction is down to 15 minutes.

> The system uses a 15-minute tick frequency for timer requests. A time-triggered background task is scheduled on the next tick after FreshnessTime elapses. If the OneShot property is false, FreshnessTime specifies the interval for a recurring task.

Comment: Thanks, notice that's is 15 min in WIndows Phone 8.1 is good to know.